# Comparing two vectors one value at a time without using WHILE

Tags: r, while-loop, plyr, apply

I have two tables: *df.author* and *df.post*, which are related by a one-to-many relation. Now I changed the primary key of *df.author* and I want *df.post* to mirror the change. In the following R script I use `match()` in a `while` loop to compare the foreign key of each row of *df.post* with the old primary key of *df.author* and-when they match-replace the foreign key with the new one (form a different column of *df.author*). Please consider the following:

```
foreignkey <- c("old_pk1","old_pk2","old_pk3","old_pk4","old_pk5","old_pk1","old_pk7")
df.post <- data.frame(foreignkey,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rm(foreignkey)

primarykey_old <- c("old_pk1","old_pk2","old_pk3","old_pk4","old_pk5")
primarykey_new <- c("new_pk1","new_pk2","new_pk3","new_pk4","new_pk5")
df.author <- data.frame(primarykey_old, primarykey_new, stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
rm(primarykey_old); rm(primarykey_new) 

i <- 1; N <- length(df.post$foreignkey)
while (i <= N) {
  match <- match(df.post$foreignkey[i], df.author$primarykey_old)
  if (!is.na(match)) {
    df.post$foreignkey[i] <- df.author$primarykey_new[match]
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
rm(N); rm(i); rm(match)
```

The script works but because of `while` doesn't scale efficiently for a large dataset. I have read that using `apply()` (in my case by converting to a matrix) is usually better than using `while`. I wonder if it also applies to my case. Because if you look at the loop you see I need to go through every single row of the dataframe to get the foreign key and then through out *df.author* for a `match()`. 
Can I compress the computational time by not using `while`?

Comment: This is not spelled correctly: `as.Character`. If this is really a problem with one-many possibilities, then you could construct a dataset that exhibits that feature

Comment: Sorry that line was made redundant by `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

Comment: The second issue is still unresolved. I suspect it invalidates the answer I am giving, but it's your responsibility now to construct a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do everything in a loopless fashion:

```
df.post$foreignkey[
    !length(match(df.post$foreignkey, df.author$primarykey_old))==0] <- # the test
    df.author$primarykey_new[match(df.post$foreignkey, df.author$primarykey_old)]
```

Logic : Only if there is a match then replace the existing value with the matching value.

Comment: If I understand correctly `match()` return only the first match. So what does it happen here if there are duplicates values in `df.post$foreignkey`? (It's a many-to-one relation from `df.post` to `df.author`). I can check that it works indeed, I just don't understand how...

Comment: I edited my question to add the case where in `foreignkey` there's a value not present in `primarykey_old`. With this solution the nomatching values in `foreignkey` are replaced with empty values. Is it possible to avid modifying the value in `foreignkey` for nomatch?